# Trying to save a game, but gets stuck every time. output log is saying "bag missing???""

Tags: unity-game-engine, save, output

I'm trying to save a game, but each time I save, the game jams up. The screen just freezes. I can unfreeze it by pressing escape and the game just continues. However, the save doesn't register. When I go back to the start menu and select the tile where I tried to save, the game freezes completely, even though it seems empty. Anybody got any ideas what's going wrong?

```html
7/05/2020 16:07:50 / Save[0] bag missing???
7/05/2020 16:09:09 / Save[0] Error during SaveInfos : Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteSyntaxException: 43 values for 40 columns
  at Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.GetNextStatement (System.IntPtr pzStart, System.IntPtr& pzTail, System.IntPtr& pStmt) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, System.Boolean want_results, System.Int32& rows_affected) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at DBManager.SaveInfos (CTEnum+SaveTableDataKind _kind, System.Int32 _num) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at DataMgr.SaveGameData () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at SaveNLoad.SaveSlot () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.GUI+WindowFunction.Invoke (System.Int32 id) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall`1[T1].Invoke (T1 args0) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Reflection.EventInfo+AddEventAdapter.Invoke (System.Object _this, System.Delegate dele) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ReleaseMouse (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, UnityEngine.GameObject currentOverGo) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMousePress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerInputModule+MouseButtonEventData data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMouseEvent (System.Int32 id) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
7/05/2020 16:09:28 / Save[1] Error during SaveInfos : Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteSyntaxException: 43 values for 40 columns
  at Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.GetNextStatement (System.IntPtr pzStart, System.IntPtr& pzTail, System.IntPtr& pStmt) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteReader (System.Data.CommandBehavior behavior, System.Boolean want_results, System.Int32& rows_affected) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteCommand.ExecuteNonQuery () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at DBManager.SaveInfos (CTEnum+SaveTableDataKind _kind, System.Int32 _num) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at DataMgr.SaveGameData () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at SaveNLoad.SaveSlot () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.GUI+WindowFunction.Invoke (System.Int32 id) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.InvokableCall`1[T1].Invoke (T1 args0) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.Events.UnityEvent.Invoke () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at System.Reflection.EventInfo+AddEventAdapter.Invoke (System.Object _this, System.Delegate dele) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents.Execute[T] (UnityEngine.GameObject target, UnityEngine.EventSystems.BaseEventData eventData, UnityEngine.EventSystems.ExecuteEvents+EventFunction`1[T1] functor) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ReleaseMouse (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerEventData pointerEvent, UnityEngine.GameObject currentOverGo) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMousePress (UnityEngine.EventSystems.PointerInputModule+MouseButtonEventData data) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.ProcessMouseEvent (System.Int32 id) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.StandaloneInputModule.Process () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0 
  at UnityEngine.EventSystems.EventSystem.Update () [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on sql, but this error seams do describe that you are trying to save more values than you have variables  for

`7/05/2020 16:09:09 / Save[0] Error during SaveInfos : Mono.Data.SqliteClient.SqliteSyntaxException:` **43 values for 40 columns**

Comment: Yeah, I saw that as well. What's curious is that on some computers it doesn't do this and on some it does. So why would it save more values than there are variables for on some pc's, and not on others...?

Comment: The easiest way do get more information about this is to Debug.Log the variables you or the sql reader tries to save. Because everything else is just guessing. Also if it's system dependent it is even more difficult to figgure out by just looking at the error messages.

Comment: How do I go about debugging? Do I debug the .db savefile or the log? Any article I could read about that?

Comment: As I said. I'm not an expert on sql. But the save file doesn't seem promising because there is not enough space for the variables you want to save. So there is no additional information. Can you debug your function that takes a variable and saves it? I don't know how that works in sql but that would be a good point to start.